# Why is my dock is not overlaying on all windows in macOS?

Tags: macos

I am on macOS 13.2.1 (22D68).

My dock menu is not overlaying on entire different programs and windows making applications leave a small space in the end.

I have checked all the settings and nothing needs to be changed.

Any reason? See attached image.

> [image]

> [image]

I want something like below:

> [image]

The point is, the dock is over the Chrome, giving Chrome full-screen view on the screen. Like, Chrome is now fully fitted in the screen, instead of cluttered in the 1/3 of the screen like the above 2 images.

FWIW, how I made it like 3rd image is, I checked/unchecked the option "Automatically hide and show the Dock" and it worked but once I closed and re-opened Chrome or Finder its acts again like 1st and 2nd image.

Comment: I’m a bit confused… What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I updated my question. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think so. So [using your first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVkqT.jpg) as an example, to the left of the dock is blank space and you want that to have Chrome in that space instead of it being just blank space, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.
But on both the left and right sides it is blank space. 
How did I make it like 3rd image is, I checked/unchecked the option "Automatically hide and show the Dock" and it worked but once I closed and re-opened Chrome or Finder it acted again like 1st and 2nd image.

Comment: Makes sense. Hopefully someone will have an answer.